# Reciprocal of Riemann zeta function and Moebius function

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

According to Wikipedia, the Dirichlet series
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{a_n}{n^s}$$ converges absolutely for $Re(s)>k+1$ where $a_n$ is $O(n^k)$.

For the reciprocal of Riemann zeta function $\frac1{\zeta(s)}$, $a_n=\mu(n)$. RH conjectures that the series converges for $\Re(s)>\frac12$.

Am I allowed to thus say that RH conjectures $\mu(n)$ is $O(n^{-\frac12})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood what Wikipedia says. From the convergence theory of Dirichlet series it follows that if the Mertens function $M(x) = \sum_{n \leq x}\mu(n)$ is $O(x^{1/2 + \epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then RH holds. You are certainly not allowed to say that $\mu(n)$ is $O(n^{-1/2})$, for $\mu(n)$ takes only the values $0,{\pm}1$, so on your say-so it would have only finitely many nonzero values. Then $\zeta(s)$ would have no zeros at all! Which is false. BTW the approach towards RH via $M(x)$ is (probably) due to Stieltjes around 1885.

Comment: And is it recently disproved?

Comment: Is what disproved?

Comment: The Mertens conjecture?

Comment: If by "Mertens conjecture" you mean the statement that $M(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \epsilon})$, then (a) the conjecture is not due to Mertens, and (b) it is not disproved, and (c) if it were disproved, that would also disprove RH. In fact, Mertens did not make such a conjecture; he was investigating (by hand calculations) a very tentative conjecture $|M(x)| \leq \sqrt{x}$ that Stieltjes made in 1885. Mertens calculated $M(x)$ up to $x=5000$, and found that the square root bound held. But in 1985 Odlyzko and the Riele disproved the square root bound.